# is there a way in c++ not to generate debug information for a specific portion of a project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, eigen

I am recently working with Eigen library with visual C++ to solve a very large sparse linear system. Program works really fast in Release mode, but in Debug mode it takes hours to solve. I traced the timing, the program takes long time in "solve" function of Eigen. I want to build the project in debug mode as I need to debug a lot. Now is there a way not to generate debug information for Eigen portion? Or is there any other workaround for this problem?

Comment: The issue is not connected to debug information, it is optimization settings.

Comment: @teivaz is right. Eigen is a library that relies _strongly_ on the optimizer doing its job. When I use Eigen, I always build in a _RelWithDebInfo_ mode (with CMake+gcc, that usually means `-O2 -g`), whereas Debug mode usually implies `-O0` (no optimization).

Comment: Test your program the Smart Way™.  You will find 99.9% of the bugs with a well-chosen *small* dataset that takes well less than a minute to execute.  Only test the runs-for-hours scenario with the Release build, that explores the remaining 0.1% memory and execution time limitations.  If your program does not scale like that right now then make it scale, a program that cannot be debugged is not a program you can ever ship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable debug information and enable code optimisation per file.

In the Solution Explorer right click on the file that contains the `Eigen` function, then chose Properties.

In the dialog that appears, choose the C/C++->Optimisation and chose the same options you have in Release mode.

Then choose C/C++->General and under "Debug Information Format" choose "None". But the presence of debug information has probably no influence on execution speed.

Answer (score 8):

@MichaelWalz's answer is great, but I would like to add (as I have outlined in my comment to your question) that *I strongly recommend not using Eigen in Debug mode*.

Eigen is a highly efficient, yet very usable matrix library.  It achieves its efficiency through a lot of “template magic”, using many layers of abstraction, and relies on the compiler's optimization stages to produce highly efficient code.

Debug mode usually implies that the compiler creates debug symbols, but also disables optimization.  In GCC/clang, it is usually equivalent to `-O0 -g`; I believe in Visual Studio it corresponds to `/O0 /DEBUG`.

I recommend building all code that uses Eigen in a “release-with-debug-info” mode instead (what CMake calls `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo`).  This means that you allow the compiler to optimize, while still generating debug symbols.  In GCC/clang, this is usually equivalent to `-O2 -g`; I believe in Visual Studio it corresponds to `/O2 /DEBUG`.  Personally I have had very good experiences like this; IMHO it is only in very rare circumstances that you actually need to disable optimization completely.